# UIViewController in a UITabBarController without tab bar item

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

So I have this application where I have a view controller (which I want to appear first when the app starts) and a tab bar controller. I also have other navigation bar controllers that are in the tab bar controller. I want to place my view controller on top of the tab bar controller. Making the tab bar controller the parent of the view controller would be better though.

[image: like this :]

But take note, I do not want a tab bar item to represent the view controller and I want the tab bar to appear along with the view controller. I do not and would not want to use storyboards as much as possible. How can i achieve this?

Comment: So this special view controller is shown until a tab is selected, then it's removed and never accessible again?

Comment: @Wain yup. it is removed but still accessible. i'll make a "home button" on the navigation bar to make it accessible again.

Comment: So you can just add it as a subview when required and remove it when any of the tabs are tapped (in the callback), and it's all done in code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the simplest solution would be to use a screenshot of your tabBar and put it in your `HomeViewController` as a button. In this case you could use your `HomeViewController` as `rootViewController` and in the button action you set the `TabBarController` as the `rootViewController`.

Root = Home + Button
-->
Root = TabBar

Perhaps you need four buttons, if you want the correct tab to be selected.